# Sharepoint List column referencing ID displays '0'

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have a calculated column in a Sharepoint list that references and displays the 'ID' field, called 'Issue ID', see below:

[image]

This seems to work fine until someone updates a ticket - at which point it seems this field then changes to 0:

[image]

Does anyone know what is causing this?  Any thoughts on how I retain the ID number for each record in this field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ID column in calculated columns is not supported, this is why it doesn't appear in the "Insert Column" list next to the formula box. Alternatively, you could use a Power Automate flow that runs on the creation of a new item to update a column using the ID column.

Comment: Thank you.  Seems like a strange gap in functionality here.  I appreciate your help, nonetheless.

Comment: If you think the answer has helped, please upvote or mark the answer as accepted to the let the community know :)